# Laravel Importing CSV throws error on rows with dates

Tags: laravel, csv-import

Import.php

```
...
return new Statement([
                    'account_number'            => $row['accountno'],
                    'account_name'              => $row['name'],
                    'reading_date'              => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['billdate']),
                    'due_date'                  => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['duedate']),
                ]);
...
```

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException PHP 8.1.6 9.37.0
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '10/18/2022' for column `mubsdb`.`statements`.`due_date` at row 1
INSERT INTO
  `statements` (`due_date`, `reading_date`)
VALUES
  ( 10 / 18 / 2022, 10 / 03 / 2022),
  (
    10 / 18 / 2022,
    10 / 03 / 2022
  ),
  ( 10 / 18 / 2022, 10 / 03 / 2022),
  ( 10 / 18 / 2022, 10 / 03 / 2022),
  (10/18/2022, 10/03/2022), (10/18/2022, 10/03/2022), (10/18/2022, 10/03/2022),
```

DB Structure:

```
Name                Type           Null      Default    
reading_date         date           Yes      NULL
due_date             date           Yes      NULL
```

I'm trying to import and save csv rows to my DB but I get error with dates. I tried  `\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['billdate'])` and `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['billdate'])->format('Y-m-d')` but neither seems to work

Comment: Are you using [laravel-excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel) for the import?

Comment: yes I am using that package

Answer (score 0):

weirdly, this worked.

```
'reading_date' => $row['billdate'] ? \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['billdate'])->format('m/d/Y') : null,
'due_date' => $row['duedate'] ? \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['duedate'])->format('m/d/Y') : null,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newest version of [laravel-excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel), then you'll notice at [this page](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html) a date column is exported using `Date::dateTimeToExcel`:

```php
// ...

Date::dateTimeToExcel($invoice->created_at),

// ...
```

That is because date is stored as numbers in excel, thus a datetime object needs to be converted first in order to show the value correctly.

This rule also exists in import. So personally I would add a rule in the import class to make sure that the date we're receiving is a number (which actually a date format in excel):

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class MyImport implements WithValidation
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'created_at' => ['numeric'],
        ];
    }
}
```

And then, when about to importing the data using `model`, convert the number to datetime before modifying it with Carbon:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;

// ...

return new Import([
   // ...
   
   'created_at' => Carbon::instance(Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['created_at'])),
   // or any other Carbon methods

   // ...
]);
```